# Mathematica Newmark Optimization

Tags: differential-equations, performance-tuning, numerical-integration

Here is my Mathematica code which implements the Newmark method to solve an equation of motion. The variable `ag` contains the acceleration values from an earthquake record. Is it possible to optimize this piece of code? It takes a long time to calculate a spectral response, which runs this code about 500 times, taking around 20 minutes.

The "Data.txt" can be found [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1RKQFnGvwENyM1J0L9-SwUxWrMa4Z81htLzYvjdUXYXk/edit?pref=2&pli=1%22Data.txt%22) or [here](https://pastebin.com/t7itJ7Q3).

```
Parallelize[Axel = Import["https://pastebin.com/raw/t7itJ7Q3"]];
Data = Array[{Axel[[#]][[1]], Axel[[#]][[2]]} &, Length[Axel] - 1, 2];
ag = 10 Data[[All, 2]];


M[y_] := N[
  Parallelize[
   u = fs = 
     kt = kthat = rhat = phat = v = a = ConstantArray[1., Length[ag]];
   k = 1.;
   m = 1.;
   p = -m ag;
   c = 0.1;
   fy = y;
   gamma = 1/2.; beta = 1/6.;
   v[[1]] = 0.;
   fs[[1]] = 0.;
   u[[1]] = 0.;
   a[[1]] = (p[[1]] - c v[[1]] - fs[[1]])/m;
   dt = 0.01;
   a1 = 1./(beta dt^2) m + gamma/(beta dt) c;
   a2 = 1./(beta dt) m + (gamma/beta - 1) c;
   a3 = (1/(2 beta) - 1.) m + dt (gamma/(2 beta) - 1) c;

   For[i = 1, i < Length[ag], i++,
    u[[i + 1]] = u[[i]];
    fs[[i + 1]] = fs[[i]];
    phat[[i + 1]] = p[[i + 1]] + a1 u[[i]] + a2 v[[i]] + a3 a[[i]];
    While[
     Abs[rhat[[i + 1]] = 
        phat[[i + 1]] - fs[[i + 1]] - a1 u[[i + 1]]] > 0.000001,
     u[[i + 1]] = u[[i + 1]] + rhat[[i + 1]]/(k + a1);
     If[
      (fz = fs[[i]] + k (u[[i + 1]] - u[[i]])) >= 0,
      fs[[i + 1]] = Min[fz, fy];,
      fs[[i + 1]] = Max[fz, -fy];
      ];
     ];
    v[[i + 1]] = 
     gamma/(beta dt) (u[[i + 1]] - u[[i]]) + (1. - gamma/
         beta) v[[i]] + dt (1 - gamma/(2 beta)) a[[i]];
    a[[i + 1]] = 
     1/(beta dt^2) (u[[i + 1]] - u[[i]]) - 
      1/(beta dt) v[[i]] - (1/(2 beta) - 1.) a[[i]];

    ];
   uy = fy/k;
   um = Max[Abs[u]];
   miu = Max[um/uy, 1]
   ]]
```

Here's a single run which takes quarter of a second, but implementing the function into a solver algorithm runs this around thousand times.

```
In[778]:= M[0.04343505938959662`] // AbsoluteTiming

Out[778]= {0.259419, 5.97369}
```

single solver run:

```
In[734]:= y = 6;
x = 1/y;
While[Abs[az = y - M[x]] > 0.05, 
   x = (1 - 0.1 Sign[az]) x]; // AbsoluteTiming
M[x]

Out[736]= {7.78515, Null}

Out[737]= 5.97369
```

Comment: There is a Newmark time integrator [here](https://github.com/ruebenko/IMS/blob/master/Imtek/TimeIntegrate.m) and the documentation is [here](https://github.com/ruebenko/IMS/blob/master/Imtek/Documentation/English/Packages/TimeIntegrateDocu.nb). Perhaps that's useful to you.

Comment: It might be good to add some example runs of this and some example data so that one can try it out; else one does not know if the optimization works correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tried compiling my code in C, as well as storing the Length function into a variable. It has increased the speed by a factor of 100.

```
cf = Compile[{{x, _Real}}, Block[{u, fs, kt, kthat, rhat, phat, v, a,
    dt, k, c, m, gamma, beta, fy, a1, a2, a3, p, um, uy, i, fz, l},
   l = Length[ag]; 
   u = fs = kt = kthat = rhat = phat = v = a = ConstantArray[0., l];
   k = 1.;
   m = 1.;
   p = -m ag;
   c = 0.1;
   fy = x;
   gamma = 1/2.; beta = 1/6.;
   v[[1]] = 0.;
   fs[[1]] = 0.;
   u[[1]] = 0.;
   a[[1]] = (p[[1]] - c v[[1]] - fs[[1]])/m;
   dt = 0.01;
   a1 = 1./(beta dt^2) m + gamma/(beta dt) c;
   a2 = 1./(beta dt) m + (gamma/beta - 1) c;
   a3 = (1/(2 beta) - 1.) m + dt (gamma/(2 beta) - 1) c;

   For[i = 1, i < l, i++,
    u[[i + 1]] = u[[i]];
    fs[[i + 1]] = fs[[i]];
    phat[[i + 1]] = p[[i + 1]] + a1 u[[i]] + a2 v[[i]] + a3 a[[i]];
    While[
     Abs[rhat[[i + 1]] = 
        phat[[i + 1]] - fs[[i + 1]] - a1 u[[i + 1]]] > 0.000001,
     u[[i + 1]] = u[[i + 1]] + rhat[[i + 1]]/(k + a1);
     If[
      (fz = fs[[i]] + k (u[[i + 1]] - u[[i]])) >= 0,
      fs[[i + 1]] = Min[fz, fy];,
      fs[[i + 1]] = Max[fz, -fy];
      ];
     ];
    v[[i + 1]] = 
     gamma/(beta dt) (u[[i + 1]] - u[[i]]) + (1. - gamma/
         beta) v[[i]] + dt (1 - gamma/(2 beta)) a[[i]];
    a[[i + 1]] = 
     1/(beta dt^2) (u[[i + 1]] - u[[i]]) - 
      1/(beta dt) v[[i]] - (1/(2 beta) - 1.) a[[i]];

    ];
   uy = fy/k;
   um = Max[Abs[u]];
   miu = Max[um/uy, 1]
   ], CompilationTarget -> "C", Parallelization -> True]
```

Running times for the C-compiled version:

```
In[870]:= cf[0.0434] // AbsoluteTiming

Out[870]= {0.00213977, 5.9806}

In[887]:= y = 6;
x = 1/y;
While[Abs[az = y - cf[x]] > 0.05,x = (1 - 0.1 Sign[az]) x]; // AbsoluteTiming
cf[x]

Out[889]= {0.0474829, Null}

Out[890]= 5.97369
```

I'd appreciate it if you could point out any other possible optimizations ;)